# Lid switch on notebook stopped working after update. How can I fix it?

Tags: power-management

The lid switch of the notebook Lenovo Thinkpad X230i had worked just fine: closing the lid led to a suspend as expected. After an update of the system on the 18th of September the lid switch seems to be not recognized any more.

If I manually click on "Suspend", it works fine, so suspending is not the core of the problem.

I tried to read the "Lid" state, by entering `while [ 1 ]; do cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state; sleep 1; done` in the terminal and also by trying `watch -n 4 'upower -d | grep lid-'`, but the reported lid state is always "OPEN". My strong assumption is that the lid switch did not physically break at the same time when I did the update. Also, the notebook is just three weeks old.

Is there a way that I can fix the correct reading of the lid state in Ubuntu? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I figured out that it actually is a hardware problem with the lid switch. Just closing the lid does not lead to recognition of the closure by the switch. I need to press with a finger at a particular point on the lid. This is a hardware and not software problem. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is the lid close switch located?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem comes from the lack of systemd according to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911154433/http://www.infty.nl/wordpress/2012/12/gnome-3-on-ubuntu-raring-and-suspend/).

From the same webpage, there is a workaround: put the following into `/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post`, and make it executable.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
   pm-suspend
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin for your quick answer. Unfortunately, the workaround does not work for me. I assume that I have a somewhat lower level problem, because the state in /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state never changes anymore to "closed".

Comment: Since Sachin hinted to systemd in his previous comment, I had a look again at the update log (see link above). Is it possible that an update of these packages here "destroyed" Ubuntu's ability to read the lid switch state?

Comment: These here: *** 2013-09-18 21:03:35 upgrade libudev-dev:amd64 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:03:36 upgrade libudev1:i386 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:03:38 upgrade libudev1:amd64 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:04:04 upgrade libsystemd-daemon0:amd64 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:04:05 upgrade libsystemd-login0:amd64 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:04:06 upgrade systemd-services:amd64 198-0ubuntu11.1 198-0ubuntu11.2 *** 2013-09-18 21:04:33 upgrade ubuntu-system-service:all 0.2.4 0.2.4.1

Comment: Assuming this might be a systemd/libudev problem I added a question here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1233091 Do you think the problem could be related to the update of that package?